# pymongo count by multiple groups for a merge

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm looking to create an on-demand materialized view for a time consuming query as the table will likely contain 2-4M entries all the time.

What I have so far is:

```
events.history.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"sevr":{"$ne":"NO_ALARM"}}},
  {"$group": {"_id": ["$name", "$sevr"], "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
  {"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])},
])
```

which gives me the following output format:

```
[
  {'_id': ["name_1", "SEVR_1"], 'count': <count>},
  {'_id': ["name_1", "SEVR_2"], 'count': <count>},
  {'_id': ["name_2", "SEVR_1"], 'count': <count>},
  {'_id': ["name_2", "SEVR_2"], 'count': <count>},
  ...
]
```

But if I try to merge that into a materialized view it obviously fails because the _id is a list. What I really need is the following:

```
[
  {'_id': "name_1", 'count': {"SEVR_1":<count>, "SEVR_2":<count>}},
  {'_id': "name_2", 'count': {"SEVR_1":<count>, "SEVR_2":<count>}},
  ...
]
```

At the moment, all I can think to do is run the query, modify the result to fit with the desired output, then update the materialized view manually, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Do I just have the query wrong and can get it to work in a nice on-liner?

Unless there's a method using vanilla mongodb/pymongo where we can auto detect changes (without replicas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any data as field names brings extra complications, but not insurmountable ones.

If I understand correctly, here's one way you could do it.

```js
events.history.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "sevr": {"$ne": "NO_ALARM"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "name": "$name",
        "sevr": "$sevr"
      },
      "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }
  },
  {"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.name",
      "count": {
        "$mergeObjects": {
          "$arrayToObject": [
            [{"k": "$_id.sevr", "v": "$count"}]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_N10XCiMsNy).

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hr, that's an excellent solution. Not only does it give me the result I want, but it's 2x quicker than the not-quite-correct solution I offered